# How do you put an if statement inside of a try catch exception?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, try-catch

Hello I'm working on method that is reading a file and outputting something. My code worked before I put my if statement in the code, I can't seem to figure out the exception part with the if statement inside of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void reader(String file, String argument) {
    File myList = new File(file);
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(myList);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if(myList.equals(argument)){
            System.out.print(s);
            System.out.println();
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("do something");
            }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Fix the code's formatting, and the reason should become apparent to you. Your curly braces are not balanced properly.

Comment: Can you provide us with the error you get when running the file

Comment: @JosephAttia probably none as this code can't run

Comment: @jhamon yes I'm asking for the error

Comment: @JosephAttia there is no error, the code cannot compile.

Comment: He is just missing a closing bracket after his `else`.

Comment: There is always a compiler error if the code cannot compile. This error will almost always give you an idea about what the problem is.

Comment: Why do you check if a file equals a string?

Comment: The code below fixed my problem. if theres anyone with high repuation they shoud upvote or give it a check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 3 points where a condition could be met (I, II, III).

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(myList)) {
    if (!in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.print("do something I");
    } else {
        boolean uneq = false;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (myList.equals(argument)) {
                System.out.print(s);
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print("do something II");
                uneq = true;
            }
        }
        if (uneq) {
            System.out.print("do something III");
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked! Thanks so much! Everyone else said there was something wrong with my question, not sure why anyone downvoted this!